# vs code live sass compiler not updating files

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

So someone has asked something fairly similar before but didn't get an answer.

I am learning SASS and am using the live sass compiler in vs code but it is not updating anything. The only way I can get the app.css file to show the changes is to press the watching button and basically reset the thing. It didn't used to do this. All changes were shown as soon as I saved the file. There doesn't seem to be anything in the output terminal that shows an issue. Is this the only way to see live changes in sass files when working in a local environment or is there a better way.

```
.header {
  height: 8vh;
  background-color: #131921;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px 20px;

  &__logo {
    width: 100px;
    object-fit: contain;
    margin: 0 20px;
  }

  &__search {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 35px;
  }

  &__searchIcon {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 36px !important;
    width: 36px !important;
    background-color: #cd9042;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0 !important;
  }

  &__searchInput {
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px !important;
  }

  &__nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
  &__boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 10px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-align: left;
  }

  &__boxesFirstLine {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }

  &__boxesSecondLine {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 9px;
  }

  &__basketText {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 9px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is the content of the scss file. I don't think it is an issue with this as it works as soon as the compiler is restarted.

Comment: versions of your sass compiler and vscode?

Comment: vs code version 1.49 sass compiler 3.0.0

Comment: can you show us a screenshot of part of your IDE, the part where it shows the compilation status?

Comment: Do you mean the output terminal? If so

Comment: Compiling Sass/Scss Files: 
c:\Users...........location.............\App.scss
c:\Users\...........location.............\\Header.scss
--------------------
Generated :
c:\Users\...........location.............\App.css
c:\Users\...........location.............\App.css.map
--------------------
Generated :
c:\Users...........location.............\Header.css
c:\Users...........location.............\Header.css.map
--------------------
Watching...
--------------------

Comment: what compiler are you using? and what version?

Comment: vs code version 1.49 sass compiler 3.0.0 as it says above

Comment: sorry for the lack of followup on this Mark. Umm, can you take a screenshot of your visual studio code when this happens, in particular the terminal msg? The way it works on my end is that every time I open MVSC or a .sass file, I have to click 'watch sass' once. Once the status changes to 'watching....' then and only then does saving a file trigger the compilation to css.

Comment: Found out the reason it is not working. The header part is in a seperate file to the main scss file and imported in. The problem seems to be that only changes in the main file are being watched. I've managed to fudge it by making a slight change to the main and saving every time I want to update the the changes in the header file. Think it's a settings issue but I haven't had chance to look through the docs to see how to fix it

Comment: please write this as your own answer and mark it as accepted

Comment: It's not a fix though is it, it's a bypass of an issue which would be terrible if that's the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For all those facing issues with *Live Sass Compiler* not watching. Here is the solution.

After our extension is installed in VScode, we are going to look at some settings.

1. Go to settings (Click on the settings icon on  `bottom-left` corner of your VSCode, and in the menu that appears click on `settings`).
2. Then a Search field will appear at the top, we will type and search for  `Live Sass Compiler`.
3. Click on `Live Sass Compiler` once it appears and again click on `Edit in Settings.json` link and add following json:

   ```
   "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
     "format": "expanded",
     "extensionName": ".css",
     "savePath": "/dist/css"
    }
   ],
   ```

Save and we are good to go.

**STEPS:** Providing Images for ease.

1. [image: Settings Icon Click]
2. [image: Click on Settings Menu]
3. [image: Live sass compiler]
4. [image]

**Now FOLDER STRUCTURE:**

a) After creating your project folder in any of your Disk drives. Open it in VSCode and create the `dist` folder within project folder/ root of your project. And create an `index.html` file within the `dist` folder.

b) Then create another folder within the root folder and we are going to name it `scss` and within here we are going to create a `main.scss`.

c) Then we can click on `Watch Sass` at the bootom of VSCode, Now `Live Sass Compiler` will keep watching for any changes in the `main.scss` and based on our `path` set in `settings.json`, it will automatically create the `css` folder within the `dist` folder and a `main.css` file as well which ultimately goes to production.

[image: folder structure]