# Can't compile Sass file into CSS with Live Sass Compiler

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

I can't compile Sass file into CSS using Live Sass Compiler. I have the following prompt in my main css file:

/* No CSS *//*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */

The **No CSS** might hint something, but I have no idea what.

Comment: What do you mean you "can't compile Sass file into CSS?" How are you trying to compile? What happens when you do it? Have you tried removing that annotation?

Comment: @Coding Cable: I faced this problem initially when I started SCSS and Live Sass Compiler. I have provided the answer. This will help you :) I have also provided a link with SO. That will also be helpful :) Do Accept the Answer and Vote if this answer is helpful to you [answer response](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

After our extension is installed in VScode, we are going to look at some settings.

Go to settings (Click on the settings icon on bottom-left corner of your VSCode, and in the menu that appears click on settings).

Then a Search field will appear at the top, we will type and search for Live Sass Compiler.

Click on Live Sass Compiler once it appears and again click on Edit in Settings.json link and add following json:

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
 {
  "format": "expanded",
  "extensionName": ".css",
  "savePath": "/dist/css"
 }
],
```

Save and we are good to go. I have provided a detail image by image explanation for ease here [vs-code-live-sass-compiler-not-updating-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63956833/vs-code-live-sass-compiler-not-updating-files/65429096#65429096)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Press `Ctrl` + `,` to open setting.
2. Click on the Extension Drop Down.
3. Select `Live Sass Compiler`
4. Press `Edit in setting.json` under `Live Sass Compile › Settings: Generate Map`
5. Set `liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap` to `false`.

[image]

6. Save and close the file.